# How can I order the results of an SQL query by the count of another table based on a shard ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL query that fetches posts from a database. Everything works fine,  but now I need to order the results by the number of comments each post has. The comments are on a separate table and they have a post_id column that links it to the post. I need to order the posts by the count of the comments table based on a shard ID? I have tried everything but every time I try to add something to my query it stops running completely and leaves my page blank. I need help to know where to put the other JOIN statement. This is my query:

```
    $union = "UNION ALL
                ( 
                    SELECT DISTINCT wallposts.p_id,wallposts.is_profile_notes,wallposts.times_viewed,wallposts.columnTimesShared,
                    wallposts.marked,wallposts.secure_id,wallposts.reshared,wallposts.group_id,
                    wallposts.totaluploads,wallposts.WallUploadID,wallposts.type,
                    wallposts.value,wallposts.media,wallposts.youtube,wallposts.post_type,
                    wallposts.privacy,wallposts.tagedpersons,wallposts.with_friends_tagged,wallposts.emotion_head,wallposts.selected_emotion,wallposts.title,
                    wallposts.url,wallposts.description,wallposts.cur_image,
                    wallposts.uip,wallposts.likes,wallposts.userid,
                    wallposts.posted_by,wallposts.post as postdata,wallusers.*, 
                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - wallposts.date_created AS TimeSpent,

                    PosterTable.mem_pic as posterPic, PosterTable.gender as posterGender,PosterTable.oauth_uid as poster_oauth_uid, PosterTable.username as posterUsername, 
                    PosterTable.mem_fname as posterFname,PosterTable.work as posterWork, 
                    PosterTable.mem_lname as posterLname,walllikes_track.id as PostLikeFound,wallposts.date_created 

                    FROM 
                        wallusers,wallusers as PosterTable, wallposts 
                    LEFT JOIN walllikes_track
                        ON wallposts.p_id = walllikes_track.post_id AND walllikes_track.member_id = ".$user_id." 
                    WHERE
                        wallusers.active = 1 
                    AND
                        PosterTable.active = 1
                    AND
                        wallposts.group_id IN (".$groups.")
                    AND
                        wallposts.group_id != 0
                    AND
                        PosterTable.mem_id = wallposts.posted_by
                    AND
                        wallposts.marked < ".$this->flagNumber."
                    AND
                        wallusers.mem_id = wallposts.posted_by ) ";
```

The comments table is called wallcomments and it has a column called post_id. I know I need to use JOIN and COUNT but I don't know where to put it within my current code.

Comment: Add an additional join to a subquery which finds comment counts per post and use that.  I can't give an exact answer because so many details are missing, and your query is in a mess.

Comment: Where should I insert the JOIN? That is my dilemma. Whenever I make any changes to the query. It stops running completely.

Comment: Yes, because your query is sprawling and hard to understand, as is the question.  Next time, ask a better question by showing a minimal example of your problem.  Nobody can reproduce the query you have now, because there is not even any data to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, I didn't run but i updated it.

```
SELECT wallposts.p_id,wallposts.is_profile_notes,wallposts.times_viewed,wallposts.columnTimesShared,
                wallposts.marked,wallposts.secure_id,wallposts.reshared,wallposts.group_id,
                wallposts.totaluploads,wallposts.WallUploadID,wallposts.type,
                wallposts.value,wallposts.media,wallposts.youtube,wallposts.post_type,
                wallposts.privacy,wallposts.tagedpersons,wallposts.with_friends_tagged,wallposts.emotion_head,wallposts.selected_emotion,wallposts.title,
                wallposts.url,wallposts.description,wallposts.cur_image,
                wallposts.uip,wallposts.likes,wallposts.userid,
                wallposts.posted_by,wallposts.post as postdata,wallusers.*, 
                UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - wallposts.date_created AS TimeSpent,

                PosterTable.mem_pic as posterPic, PosterTable.gender as posterGender,PosterTable.oauth_uid as poster_oauth_uid, PosterTable.username as posterUsername, 
                PosterTable.mem_fname as posterFname,PosterTable.work as posterWork, 
                PosterTable.mem_lname as posterLname,walllikes_track.id as PostLikeFound,wallposts.date_created 

                FROM 
                    wallusers,wallusers as PosterTable, wallposts 
               WHERE
                    wallusers.active = 1 
                AND
                    PosterTable.active = 1
                AND
                    wallposts.group_id IN (".$groups.")
                AND
                    wallposts.group_id != 0
                AND
                    PosterTable.mem_id = wallposts.posted_by
                AND
                    wallposts.marked < ".$this->flagNumber."
                AND
                    wallusers.mem_id = wallposts.posted_by ) " AND wallposts.p_id = walllikes_track.post_id AND walllikes_track.member_id = ".$user_id.";
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but which part did you update? I don't see any changes. I don't see anything referring to the comments table. The comments table is called wallcomments and it has a column called post_id.

Comment: i removed **UNION ALL** **JOIN** and **ON** keywords because SQL provides you to join tables without using JOIN.

For Example,
SELECT e.id, e.did,  e.name, e.sal, d.department, FROM employee e, department d WHERE e.did=d.id:

Answer (score 0):

A more readable query might look like this...

At least then we'd have a chance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.p_id
              , p.is_profile_notes
              , p.times_viewed
              , p.columnTimesShared
              , p.marked
              , p.secure_id
              , p.media...
           FROM wallposts p...
```